# next() behaves differently directly on generator vs variable with generator value

Tags: javascript, generator

Why is it that I get different results when calling next() directly on a generator, versus on a variable with the same generator assigned as its value?

All code/output below.

Below is the generator, plus variable declaration/assignment:

```
function* gen() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
};

let genVar = gen();
```

First code snippet:

```
let first = genVar.next();
console.log(first);
second = genVar.next();
console.log(second);
```

Output of first code snippet:

```
{ value: 1, done: false }
{ value: 2, done: false }
```

Second code snippet:

```
let one = gen().next();
console.log(one);
two = gen().next();
console.log(two);
```

Output of second code snippet:

```
{ value: 1, done: false }
{ value: 1, done: false }
```

My best guess at the moment is this has something to do with assignment by value/reference?

Comment: The difference is not about the variable vs the call expression as the `.next()` invocation target. It's simply that in the second example you call `gen()` *twice*, creating two different generator objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you execute the generator function, you create a brand new generator object that allows to iterate over the steps of the generator function from the start.

So in your second example, you actually create two different iterators.

Comment: That "*an iterator that allows to iterate over the generator*" wording is confusing. The generator *is* the iterator.

Comment: Agree. I have slightly amended my answer, still trying to retain the idea that the generator function is being iterated from the start by each new generator object, since it seems implied from the question that this may not be clear. Hopefully it's a bit clearer, but feel free to let me know if not.